# Can I access an instance attribute dynamically with something like a variable?

Tags: python

Is it possible access an instance attribute with something you can dynamically change like a variable? In the example below, you can see how I successfully access the `color` instance attribute with `car1.color` but unsuccessfully access this attribute with `car1.attribute` & `car1[attribute]`.

```
attribute = 'color'

class Car():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'red'
        self.shape = 'circle'

car1 = Car()

def f(attribute):
    print(car1.color)
    print(car1.attribute),
    print(car1[attribute])

f('color')
```

Comment: `getattr(car1, attribute)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `getattr`

```
getattr(car1, 'color')
```